# Snap framework - Restrict access to the whole website including its subsnaplets

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

I have a simple snaplet, which has its own routing and pretty much independent of the whole application behavior. However, as for most of the application, I want to hide the new simple snaplet under the restricted area, where only logged in users can enter.

For the root snaplet the problem solved by using simple function `restricted` which accepts a handler and checks if the user logged in, proceeding further with the given handler or redirecting to the login screen.

Here is the whole configuration:

```
appInit :: SnapletInit App App
appInit = makeSnaplet "myapp" "My Example Application" Nothing $ do
  fs <- nestSnaplet "foo" foo fooInit
  ss <- nestSnaplet "sess" sess $ 
    initCookieSessionManager "site_key.txt" "sess" (Just 3600)
  as <- nestSnaplet "auth" auth $ 
    initJsonFileAuthManager defAuthSettings sess "users.json"
  addRoutes [("content", restricted $ render "content"),
             ("login", login)]
  return $ App ss as fs

restricted :: Handler App App () -> Handler App App ()
restricted = requireUser auth (redirect "/login")

fooInit :: SnapletInit b Foo
fooInit = makeSnaplet "foo" "A nested snaplet" Nothing $ do
    addRoutes [("info", writeText "Only registered users can have acess to it")]
    return Foo
```

If I enter http://mywebsite/foo/info, I will be able to see the content of the subsnaplet without logging it. It seems to me, that I cannot protect all of the handlers implemented inside of my new `Foo` without changing that snaplet and modifying its routing. Or am I wrong?

P.S.: There is an option to use `weapSite` and check the request URL, but since it implies verification based on URL, not on the recourse, (handler in this case) it doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to use the [`wrapSite` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-1.0.0.1/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:wrapSite).  It takes an argument `(Handler b v () -> Handler b v ())`, which is exactly the type signature of your `restricted` function.

Comment: Thank you @mightybyte for your response. wrapSite was the obvious option for me as well, but if I make wrapSite restricted then I will restrict the entire website, users won't be able even to reach the login screen, neither static resources will be available. I guess I should check inside of restricted if the page is restricted or not, but what the criteria of restrictions would be? rqPathInfo?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever part of the request is appropriate to decide whether it should be restricted.  `rqPathInfo` certainly seems like a plausible one.  `rqURI` might be another one.  If we widen our perspective a bit, you could even use things like `rqHostName` or `rqClientAddr`.  Those probably aren't what you are looking for in this case, but they give an example of the kind of flexibility you have.